# (Unity) Rotate parent object by script like in editor

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, parent

I have gameobjects inside a parent game object. When I rotate the parent in axis Y with the editor using the tool "E", it rotates correctly, and I can see how it change also X and Z position to rotate centered.

When I do it by script, it only change the rotation Y value and it creates some strange efect with the static camera pointing at it.

I have tried:

```
GameObject parentobject;
Transform transf;
Vector3 pivot;
```

Option 1:

```
Update()
{    
    parentobject.transform.Rotate(0,Time.deltaTime*50f,0);    
}
```

Option 2:

```
Update()
{    
    Vector3 axisrotate= new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
    parentobject.transform.Rotate(axisrotate,1);    
}
```

Option 3:

```
Start()
{    
    bound.center = parentobject.transform.position;
    transf = parentobject.transform.root.GetComponentInChildren<Transform>();
    bound.Encapsulate(transf.position);
    pivot = bound.center;    
}
Update()
{    
    transform.root.RotateAround(pivot, Vector3.up, Time.deltaTime * 50)    
}
```

But the result is always the same.

Thanks.

Comment: `parentobject.transform.root.GetComponentInChildren<Transform>()` ... This probably just returns the parents transform again .. `GetComponentInChildren` starts the search on the root itself ... The other options do basically exactly the same thing ... could you explain a bit more what exactly you are trying vs what is happening instead?

Comment: When doing this in the editor then are you in [pivot or center mode? And in global or local axes?](https://docs.unity3d.com/uploads/Main/HandlePositionButtons_01.png) See [positioning objects](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PositioningGameObjects.html)

Comment: @derHugo I am with the rotate tool, center and local. I have just seen that in global is also working as I want.

I have two objects inside a gameobject in the hierarchy. When I select the main object and with that tool, i can select the yellow circle to rotate in Y axis. When I do that, I see in the inspector that the values from position X and Z and also moving with the rotation Y value. In the Scene I can see how it rotates from the center where the tool has appeared.

When I do that by code with those 3 options, in the inspector I only see The rotation value moving.

Comment: @derHugo And in the Scene/game I see how the objects rotates but not from the same axis as the editor. With the camera I can see how the object are moving to the camera and far away to the camera instead of beeing in the same spot just rotate. Although in the inspector the positions values are not moving.

Answer (score 0):

I have solve it with "transform.RotateAround" But the axis where do you want to rotate at, it can not be the same object. So I have create an empty object in the center of the object I wanted to rotate and use it as a reference.

Comment: Maybe add some code to your answer to help others that come across the same problem